# Density of smooth compactly supported functions in Sobolev space in bounded domain

Tags: partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, density-function

Is the space of compactly supported functions of class 2: ${\cal C}_c^2(\Omega)$ dense in the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$? under some smoothness assumptions on the a bounded open set $\Omega$ of $R^n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Functions in $C_c^2(\Omega)$ vanish in the neighborhood of the boundary. Hence, you cannot approximate functions with non-zero traces.

However, (by definition) $C_c^2(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^2(\Omega)$.